# Can suggested edit review process be fixed to show reviewers accurate diffs when there are multiple suggestions?

Tags: bug

I just edited the the title of a post in SO.  See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1240442.  I like to fix keyword spellings in titles because it at least makes the question more findable.  However, I'm finding that if my spelling fixes come in at the same time as another suggested edit containing the same spelling fixes, it looks to the reviewers like I did nothing or worse.

In my case I changed "acces" to "access" and "iner" to "inner" in the title.  That's all.  Another user must have beaten me because they changed the same things in the title and fixed some typos in the body (okay, so their suggested edit was better, I admit it).

Because of the roughly coinciding edits (especially in the title), it looked to the reviewers like

1. I had done nothing in the title,
2. I was the one to introduce the typos in the post body (because my edits had not changed them over the original, but the other reviewer had fixed them).

As a result, our dear reviewers smacked me down with gusto:

- (2x) This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on
  the existing post.
- (1x) This edit introduces spam, defaces the post
  in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.

In an era that does not permit duels to defend one's honor, I am beside myself with agitation over these aspersions.  I am pursuing counseling.  Duels are cheaper.

However, the **main issue is that reviewers apparently have no hope of interpreting the situation correctly, given the incorrect diffs they are shown by the tools in this kind of simultaneous edit scenario**.

I contend this is broken.  Wikipedia can diff nearly simultaneous revisions correctly.  Stack Overflow are you going to let this stand?  Are we men and women or mice and mice?

Comment: Mwah, collisions occasionally happen. Just shrug it off.

Comment: Mwah is right.  However, Wikipedia's revision history feature can handle this.  Ergo, so can SO.  It's a matter of honor!  Mwah!

Comment: It's just a flesh wound!

Comment: A mere scratch.

Comment: This one is a bit weird as if you look at the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14044738/revisions) it appears like I barely changed your edit at all when in fact all the changes to the body in revision 2 are ones I made... or maybe it's because I was re-doing what you removed with the colliding edit...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards.  Yeah, that's related to what I'm getting at.  The display of diffs is just plain wrong when there are collisions.  However, in this case, I think I was two revisions too late in a sense.  My stuff looked close to identical with talonmies in the title, and it looked like I reverted his spelling fixes in the body.

Comment: Working as designed. Not a real problem.

Comment: I understand your pain, but it's really not the end of the world. This is an edge case, the developers probably have more important things to work on. Anyway my tip is to avoid editing so quickly, let at least 5 minutes pass before editing and most chances you won't collide with other edits like that.

Comment: @ChrisGerken: Then, I'd say working as mis-designed.  The diff screens are presenting inaccurate information to reviewers.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd.  Understood on a priority of this.  But it's a bug nonetheless.  So, a low-priority bug.

Comment: Hmm.. 7779 [total bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) of which 3152 [are fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+status-completed) and 1030 [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+status-bydesign) - more than enough for looong time!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That's fine.  Prioritization is what it is.  I just was a bug called a bug.  And someday, it will be fixed.

Comment: "was a bug" => "want a bug" in previous comment.  Not that I wasn't also a bug.